# Why accessing this json sub elements by index raises this error?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

this is the part of the json

```
        "feature_id" = (
            3047,
            3084,
            3095,
            3100,
            3121,
            3124,
            3182,
            3272,
            3273,
            3274
        );
```

this is how I access json, I use Alamofire.

```
var features_id = self.jsonD["results"]!["place_basic_info"]!!["feature_id"]!!
```

now the problem is in here

```
features_id[0] as? String
```

the error raised is :

> ambiguous use of 'subscript'

the weird thing is this shows up when I try to build for the device, but not when running, how to solve this problem ? and why it shows up?

Comment: You have to give the right type to the compiler. Like `if let ... = features_id as? [Int] { ... }` for example. Right now the compiler doesn't know that `features_id` is an array.

Comment: you can post this as an answer.

Comment: @DeyaEldeen Side note:You should consider naming array variables a plural name (such as "feature_ids").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ambiguous use of 'subscript'

The issue is that the compiler doesn't know that `features_id` is an array, so it is unable to subscript it by index.

You have to give the object's type to the compiler, for example with optional binding and casting:

```
if let featID = features_id as? [Int] {
    // here featID is features_id unwrapped as an array of Ints
}
```

Comment: You can even use variable shadowing: `if let features_id = features_id as? [Int]...`

Comment: I love that feature. I hate having to come up with arbitrary minor name changes to avoid name collisions.